# Bash script via ssh does not have $PATH

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh

I'm trying to run bash script via ssh. To do this I run command:

```
ssh me@server 'bash -s ' < script.sh
```

The problem is that when I run script like this I don't have my `$PATH` variable (i.e. if I log into server normally, `ant -v` works fine, but doing this in script will show message that bash doesn't recognize command `ant`).

In my `script.sh` I have lines:

```
source /etc/profile
source ~/.profile
source ~/.bashrc
```

But it doesn't help. Only writing `PATH="$PATH:path-to-ant` helps

Comment: Does `source ~/.bash_profile` work?

Comment: @Radoo I don't have this file on ssh server

Comment: Then I guess the path you're looking for is set in some file in `/etc/profile.d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ssh me@server 'bash -il -s ' < script.sh
```